# Handling errors with vite dev server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

When working with vite,
there an UI when code is incorrect and contains error.(see picture below)
[image: vite error]

Is there an api in vite to handle this modal and show in controlled manner ?
I would show my own modal for this error.

Thanks for your response

Comment: What's your end goal here; why do you need to customize the modal that only shows up for developers working on the project?

Comment: my end goal would be to keep the standart ui components that forms the appBar, the sideBar and the footer and to display the error inside it. I have tried with react-error-boundaries but it does not catch syntax errors

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's probably not going to happen. What if the component that hosts your app bar, side bar and footer would have a syntax error?

Comment: The idea wloud be that the app bar, side bar and footer would not change often. On the contrary, content component change more often and errors coming from them would be displayed in a modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vite does not have a direct API to replace or customize the error pop up. The pop up is part of the Vite development server.